# How many rationals $\dfrac{m}{n}$ with denominator at most $10$ are in the interval $(0,3)$?

Tags: real-analysis

How many rationals $\dfrac{m}{n}$ with denominator $n$ at most $10$ are in interval $(0,3)$ ?

How about in the interval $(1, 20)$? How about in the interval $(a,b)$?

Here is one approach: count one by one the number of such fractions in the interval $(0,1)$ and scale the results to other intervals.

Comment: Well, there is the Euler's totient function, which a master's student recommended I use. It has something to do with relatively prime numbers, and... other than that, nothing. And I do not think a function that is not in Rudin would be used to solve a problem in Rudin.

Comment: Some links to get you started.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function ; https://oeis.org/A002088

Comment: Certainly you can do the first question yourself, just by writing them down. Then a little thought should show you how to do the other two questions. Or, do what you suggest in your last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the links, Dan. They were very helpful!

Comment: Seems to be less clear as o what does the author mean.

Answer (score 0):

We wish to count only the cases where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, how many numbers between $a$ and $b$ can be expressed as $\frac{x}{b}$ with $x$ relatively prime to $b$? There are $\varphi n$ congruences mod $n$ relatively prime to $n$ and $x$ can go from $an$ to $bn$ so there are $(a-b)\varphi n$ ways to do it.

Since $n$ can go from $1$ to $10$ we want $(a-b)\sum_{n=1}^{10}\varphi n$

Comment: I do not quite understand several of your points, but I mostly need help trying to unpack the following statement: "There are φn congruences mod n relatively prime to n."

Comment: I think Jorge means there are $\phi(n)$ numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function that you mentioned in one of your comments.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. Jorge: why x/b? This seems to suggest that our denominator can be at most b, which is 3 in the question. But the denominator can actually be at most 10. And could you elaborate on why the summation of phi(n) is being multiplied by (a-b)? And shouldn't it be (b-a)?